# How to make text-view center in android?

Tags: android, custom-action

I am working on a action bar i had design a custom action bar but the problem in that customer action bar i had used a text-view that i need it to be center.
here is my custom action bar xml code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_height="50dp"
 >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
     />
  </LinearLayout>
```

here is my java code for enabling custome action bar to that activity.

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customactionbar, null);
    TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#f8f8f8")));
    Typeface fontt = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "helvetica.ttf");
    mTitleTextView.setTypeface(fontt);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setIcon(
               new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

Comment: you are not using custom action bar its default

Comment: use Relative Layout instead of Linear layout

Comment: add this to ur xml `android:gravity="center"` for `TextView`

Comment: @prabhakaran done this but this too not work for me

Comment: @HiteshMatnani then accept the answer or post ur answer

Comment: it is not the problem with your layout, can you upload the screen shot please

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with `Relative Layout` in your xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/title_text"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
          android:textColor="#000000"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:text="@string/app_name"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you add screenshot of your app

Comment: http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android check this example and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your layout as :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Hopefully this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to android , but i think it works

what you need

1) A `relativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_height="50dp"
 >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:typeface="serif" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: @HiteshMatnani use  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a layout? Why don't you have a single TextView in your customactionbar.xml file that has `android:gravity="center"` and width and height set to `match_parent`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add three attributes in your TextView remove any other gravity attribute

```
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i had done this to but this working! as in graphical layout its show perfect but in costume action bar it center property is not working correct!

Comment: Then check your code in Activity i think this is problem of your activity

Comment: thanks please you can check my activity code that i had mention in my above question!